# Group a year of dates into months and weeks?

Tags: javascript

In an ideal world this would happen on the backend side before the rendering, but in my use case that doesn't seems possible :( So im wondering if it possible to group a year worth of dates into months and weeks?

The dates array contains additional information that has been trimmed so for the purpose of this post.

```
const dates = [
  {
    id: 1,
    date: '2022-01-01'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    date: '2022-01-02'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    date: '2022-01-03'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    date: '2022-01-04'
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    date: '2022-01-05'
  },
    // [....]
  {
    id: 361,
    date: '2022-12-27'
  },
  {
    id: 362,
    date: '2022-12-28'
  },
  {
    id: 363,
    date: '2022-12-29'
  },
  {
    id: 364,
    date: '2022-12-30'
  },
  {
    id: 365,
    date: '2022-12-31'
  },
];
```

The expected would be an array or object ordered like this:

```
├── January
│   ├── 52
│   │   ├── 2022-01-01
│   │   └── 2022-01-02
│   ├── 1
│   │   ├── 2022-01-03
│   │   ├── 2022-01-04
│   │   ├── 2022-01-05
│   │   ├── 2022-01-06
│   │   ├── 2022-01-07
│   │   ├── 2022-01-08
│   │   └── 2022-01-09
│   ├── 2
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── 3
│   │   └── ...
│   └── 4
│       └── ...
├── February
│   ├── 5
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── 6
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── 7
│   │   └── ...
│   └── 8
│       └── ...
└── Mars
    ├── 9
    │   └── ...
    ├── 10
    │   └── ...
    ├── 11
    │   └── ...
    └── 12
        └── ...
```

Probably something like this:

```
const sortedDates = {
    2022: {
        january: {
            51:{
                '2022-01-01': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-02': {
                    sunday: true
                }
            },
            1:{
                '2022-01-03': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-04': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-05': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-06': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-07': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-08': {
                    sunday: false
                },
                '2022-01-09': {
                    sunday: true
                },
            }
        },
        febuary: {
            //
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is YES, it can be done. It's unclear what your question is. How to get to week number? How to get the month? How to parse the string date? How to group? Did you try it? We don't usually ask for recommendations at SO. We try something and ask a question showing what we've tried and what's not working as expected. Otherwise the answers will be suggestions and no answer will be more right than the other. A question should be about a single issue but you're just stating a broad requirement. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0):

month is easy.

```
const date = new Date( dateString );
console.log( date.getMonth() ); // returns 0 through 11
```

week on the other hand is a huge pain. there is no inherent method for that, or day of the year. making these methods yourself is also a huge pain, because of leap years and daylight savings. To get week, it's helpful to first get day of the year.

```
function dayOfYear( dateString ) {
  const myDate = new Date(dateString);
  const yearStart = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const diff = (myDate - yearStart) + ((yearStart.getTimezoneOffset() - 
  myDate.getTimezoneOffset()) * 60 * 1000);
  const oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  return Math.floor(diff / oneDay);
}
```

You can then find the first day of the first week of the year, and use that as an offset.

```
function firstWeekStartOffset( dateString ) {
  const myDate = new Date(dateString);
  const yearStart = new Date(myDate.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  const startDayOfWeek = yearStart.getDay();
  return ( startDayOfWeek == 0 ) 0 : 7 - startDayOfWeek;
}
```

Subtract the offset from the day of the year, then divide by 7 to find which week it is.

```
const myWeek = parseInt( ( dayOfYear( dateString ) - firstWeekStartOffset( dateString ) ) / 7 ); // returns 0 through 51
```